# Firebase Authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, webstorm

Why do I get 'ref.getAuth is not a function' in the console window from the following AngularJS snippet:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var authData = ref.getAuth();
```

I'm using WebStorm for this project.

Answer (score 1):

I guess according to the newest sdk this has changed to

`"com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"`

instead of

`'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'`

and change your code

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var authData = ref.getAuth();
```

to the following:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```